# "Malformed" Anchor Tags Regex

Tags: regex

I've received "malformed" anchor tags (tags that either have no closing, no text or are self closing) via a feed I have no control over and need to correct them - here are the three examples:

- `<a class="some-class" href="www.something.com/Resource.PDF" target="_blank">` (no closing tag / not self closing)
- `<a class="some-class" href="www.something.com/Resource.PDF" target="_blank"></a>` (no text)
- `<a class="some-class" href="www.something.com/Resource.PDF" target="_blank"/>` (self closing)

I'm looking for a regular expression/set of regular expressions in C# that will find the above occurrences in an HTML string.

So far I have the following:

- `(?<anchor><a\s.+?\/{0}>)(?<text>(.*?){0})(<\/a>)` --- Finds anchors without text
- `(?<anchor><a\s.+?\/>)` ---- Finds self-closing anchors

My goal is to replace these occurrences with the resource as the text:
`<a class="some-class" href="www.something.com/Resource.PDF" target="_blank">Resource.PDF</a>`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way of doing this but in case anyone has a similar issue I ended up resolving this by finding all anchor tags and correcting them when needed instead of only looking for malformed tags - the regex I came up with is (https://regex101.com/r/xMnfY8/1):
`(?<anchor><a\s.*?href=[""'](?<anchorUrl>.+?)[""'].*?>)(?<anchorText>[\s\w]*)(?<anchorClose><\/a>|<|$|\b)`

Then I used C# code to take care of fixing the tags:

```
    public string FixAnchorTags(string html)
    {
        var result = html;
        var indexAdjustment = 0;

        foreach (Match match in _anchorTagRegex.Matches(html))
        {
            var anchor = match.Groups["anchor"];
            var anchorUrl = match.Groups["anchorUrl"];
            var anchorText = match.Groups["anchorText"];
            var anchorClose = match.Groups["anchorClose"];                

            if (anchor.Value.EndsWith("/>"))
            {                    
                result = result.Remove(anchor.Index + indexAdjustment, anchor.Length).Insert(anchor.Index + indexAdjustment, anchor.Value.Replace("/>", ">"));
                indexAdjustment -= 1;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(anchorText.Value))
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(anchorUrl.Value);
                result = result.Insert(anchorText.Index + indexAdjustment, fileName);
                indexAdjustment += fileName.Length;
            }

            if (!anchorClose.Value.Matches("</a>"))
            {
                result = result.Insert(anchorClose.Index + indexAdjustment, "</a>");
                indexAdjustment += 4;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```